# python for xx in xxs: can't enter again in pymongo?

Tags: python, pymongo

simple code:

```
models = db.live.chans.find()
for m in models:
    print m,"line1"
for m in models:
    print m,'line2'
```

the above code can't print the 'line2', and I must :

```
models = db.live.chans.find()
for m in models:
    print m,"line1"
for m in models:
    print m,'line2'
```

where I do wrong? or maybe the cursor can't loop again?

Comment: I don't see the difference between your two code samples.

Comment: Is it just me, or are those two code snippets identical?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `models` is the result-set returned from a DB query.
If you want to re-use it you'll have to save it first (using a for loop):

```
saved_data = []
for m in models:
    saved_data.append(m)
```

now you can iterate `saved_data` as many times as you want:

```
for m in saved_data:
    print m,"line1"

for m in saved_data:
    print m,"line2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Cursor works like File Pointer. If iterating over it once, it points to the end of query results. You have to do **rewind(**) to reset it.

```
models = db.live.chans.find()
for m in models:
    print m,"line1"

models.rewind()
for m in models:
    print m,'line2
```

You can use property **alive** to check whether this cursor has the potential to return more data.

```
models = db.live.chans.find()
print models.alive # True
for m in models:
    print m,"line1"
print models.alive # False
models.rewind()
print models.alive # True
```

If using the same result data many times, you can save the returned data in your own local memory.